# C# grammar in BNF or EBNF Parser generator for F#

Tags: c#-4.0, f#, grammar, bnf, ebnf

I'm looking for BNF grammar for C# v4 that I can feed to fsyacc or if I can't find that an EBNF based parser generator that can output F#.

**EDIT:**
I'm not looking to write a parser for C# but an experimental parser for a very similar grammar and since there's a huge literal overlap between the two grammars I find it easier to start with the C# grammar and simply change the bits that deviates. However the only grammar for C#v4 I've found is a EBNF

an alternative answer would be a converter from EBNF to BNF

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything solid. The best option I can think of is to use the parser from the C# compiler in Mono. You should be able to compile that and use that from F# (or modify it to be more F# friendly).

Comment: @Tomas: Thanks for pointing it out. Guess I'll rewrite the EBNF grammar I have and use fsyacc. I need to be able to change the grammar. I'm not writing a C# compiler but an experimental compiler for a very similar grammar.

Comment: @TomasPetricek If you write that as an answer I'll reward you the answer. I ended up extending the mono C# compiler instead. Was a lot less work than I would have thought

Comment: I'm glad that the approach worked for you! I added is as an answer (with a few more details).

Comment: There a grammar for C# v5 in the appendices of the C# specification: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2575044/7255.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending my previous comment - I don't think there's any solid grammar for C# that could be directly usable. There are some examples, but they probably won't cover all new features (like LINQ) or won't be very well tested.

The best option that I can think of is to use the parser from the C# compiler in Mono. This is written in C#, open-source, includes all recent features (and is also fairly solid). For more information, see [Mono C# compiler](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler). You should be able to compile that and use that from F# (or modify it to be more F# friendly).

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coco/R), Coco/R is an EBNF based parser generator. And according to their [homepage](http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Research/Projects/Coco/), there is an F# port of Coco/R (last updated 2007-07-23, though, so I'd expect some breaking changes). If you end up checking it out, I'd be interested in your experience.

I did find a BNF grammer for C# v2: http://www.devincook.com/GOLDParser/grammars/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

I found some grammars [here](http://slps.github.com/zoo/index.html#cs); they seem to include up to C# 4.0.